# Windows Phone Tile Animation like Xbox Live

Tags: windows-phone-7

Xbox Live tile animation in Windows Phone is alot more dynamic than all the tile animations I was able to produce.

Is it possible to mimic that animation somehow in my live tile?

Comment: Please give a bit more description of the xbox live tile animation for those who have not seen it...

Comment: @spryno724 I'd assume he means the standard animation wit the avatar sliding in and "knocking" the text on the tile about, as well as the text "fighting back" and knocking the avatar off -- i.e. the default animation you get with the xbox live tile, as soon as you've set the phone up with xbox live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have animated live tiles to that degree, only first-party applications have access to this functionality at the moment.

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/Blog/BlogEntry=000554/BlogEntry.aspx

The only animation you get on the main desktop is the background / foreground tile flip animation, but that again is controlled by the OS.

This makes some measure of sense, otherwise the number of animated live tiles from third-party apps could fast degrade your battery.

Comment: I cant say I agree with the rational but at least I know I didnt miss something in my research. thanks ;)

Comment: @sternr The rationale is from the user perspective, not the developer perspective, (un)fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit 7.1 (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has a control called **HubTitle**, thats allow some additional (and very cool) tiles templates...

Comment: The HubTitle control is used for in-app tile animations, not for the live tile on the home screen